# Is there any difference in bucket policy to read pdf and other files (image,video,audio)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket to store my media files. It includes all types of data like mp4,mp3 jpg, and pdf. All the files are loading into my website except pdf files.

Its shows an error:

```
Access to fetch at 'bucket_url' from origin 'my_website_url' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

My bucket policy has this included:

'https://mywebsite.com/*',

Comment: That's not a bucket policy issue, it is a CORS policy issue. Please post your CORS policy and what code you are using to get this data.

Comment: The bucket url  is passing to a pdf viewer plugin via https://mywebsite.com/lib/pdfjs-dist/web/viewer.html?file=bucket_url . This is working with my production server. But not in testing server. It raise CORs issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following:
 Logged into console
 Bucket selected
 Permissions -> CORS Configurations and added the XML code
It works!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
        <CORSRule>
          <AllowedOrigin>https://example.com</AllowedOrigin>
          <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
          <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
          <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
          <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
          <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
          <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
    <CORSRule>
         <AllowedOrigin>https://*.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
         <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
         <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
         <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
         <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
         <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
         <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
   </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the CORS configuration for your bucket to allow access to resources outside your domain. You can see how to do this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html)

Comment: Thanks, Ninad. I tried with your suggestion. But not work with me.

Comment: what url did you put between `<AllowedOrigin></AllowedOrigin>`?

Comment: my testing server website url

Comment: Just for testing can you change that to *?

Comment: Yes, It works for me when uploading pdf files into s3 after adding this CORS configuration. Still not accessible with the existing pdf files in s3. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean still not accessible with existing pdf files?

Comment: the pdf files added before update the CORS configuration in S3 bucket

Comment: That is weird. Cors policy is applied at bucket level not object level. There must be something else blocking access. Anyway if you found my answer solved your issue, please mark it correct. Thanks